# Where does the 1 V voltage come from?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, voltage-measurement, npn

I have a PLC with many digital open collector outputs connected similarly to the schematic below.

If I use a multimeter and measure the voltage between the two points in the schematic, it is showing 1 V. Isn't it supposed to be 0 V? The relay coil is not connected. The measurement point is between PSU 24 V+ and relay's NO. The measurement device is a Kyoritsu DMM type KEW 2200R

[image: Schematic]

PLC's schematics:

[image: PLC]

Comment: 1V DC. Measurement device is Hioki DMM

Comment: _"Measurement device is Hioki DMM"_ - which model, and on what range?

Comment: (1) What is connected to "measure here"? (2) If you connect a load - such as a 24 V lamp - between "measure here" and 24V- does the voltage disappear? If so it's a stray and you are OK. (3) Why are you switching the negative rail? It's not all that unusual but fault-finding is generally easier with switched +24V. Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" from CircuitLab an editable schematic is saved inline with your post. No account, no screengrab, no image upload, no background grid.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the circuitlab tips. It is surely helpful. "measure here" are dmm in dc voltage mode. DMM brand and type are: Kyoritsu type KEW 2200R. Yes, the voltage dissapear when it is connected. But I am just worried, isnt it supposed to be 0V or close to 0V? I had one of my plc io burnt..

Comment: Is this an actual electromechanical relay, or a solid-state relay of some type?

Comment: it is an actual electromechanical relay

Comment: Edit the question please. People don't wish to have to read comments in order to help you.

Comment: If the meter is connected to an NO contact and the relay's coil is not energised, why should the meter read anything in particular at all?

Answer (score 0):

What model number Hioki meter, which DC volts measurement range are you using, and do you have any special measurement modes enabled on the DMM like "high input impedance"?

DC voltmeters that have very high input impedance (>= 100 MΩ) can and do measure residual/static/floating potentials left on metal bodies as if those bodies were charged plates in a capacitor.

For example: When measuring DC volts, the DT428X handheld meters have an input impedance of 1 GΩ on the 60 mV and 600 mV ranges, and the 323X HiTESTER benchtop DMMs have an input impedance of "greater than 100 MΩ" on the 200 and 2000 mV ranges.

---

**:: EDIT 1 ::**

I don't think the KEW 2200R meter is causing this. Its input impedance is 11 MΩ for the DC Volts measurement function, which likely won't indicate a persistent 1 V reading if it's connected to a small metal mass with residual charge on it.

If it's easily done, remove the relay so that you can perform out-of-circuit tests on it. With no power connected to the relay's coil, perform three continuity tests (or ohmmeter measurements) across the switch's three terminals, i.e., test the

- input-output path for the normally-closed (NC) signal path (there should be continuity (less than one ohm)
- input-output path for the normally-open (NO) signal path (there should not be continuity (infinite resistance))
- NC output pin to NO output pin (there should not be continuity (infinite resistance))

---

**:: EDIT 2 ::**

With everything connected normally but powered OFF, try a resistance measurement from the relay's NO contact to 24V- and 24V+. It should be infinite resistance.  If the resistance is infinite, try the following:

1. Configure the DMM to measure DC volts.
2. Using jumper wires, connect a 10 kΩ 1/4 W (or higher wattage) resistor between the relay's NO terminal and ground (24V-).
3. With the system turned OFF, connect the DMM across the 10 kΩ resistor to measure the voltage drop across the resistor. Nominally, no current should be flowing through the resistor; therefore, the measured voltage drop should be approximately zero.
4. Apply power to the system.
5. Observe the indicated voltage across the resistor. It should be approximately zero volts.
6. Turn off the power to the system.
7. Using jumper wires, reconnect the 10 kΩ resistor between the relay's NO terminal and 24V+.
8. Repeat steps 3 – 7.

In step 8 if a voltage drop is measured across the resistor with the system powered ON, there's continuity somewhere between the relay's NO pin and ground. It could be the PLC software is actuating the relay (COM->NO), or the relay's socket is damaged, or a bug got under the relay socket and died and is now a resistance between the relay's NO pin and ground, or ??? (other).

Comment: sorry, the dmm used was Kyoritsu type KEW 2200R. Will that 1V voltage cause any short circuit when connected to external electronics? I had a plc io burnt a couple days ago and I am investigating.. Is it possible that this caused the short?

Comment: @AlbertTobing do you have a flyback diode on your relay coil? If not that is more likely the cause of your dead IO pin.

Comment: @AlbertTobing, if the 1 V is caused by residual, stored charge in the metal, I suspect the amount of stored charge is so small that it won't hurt anything. The next test I recommend you perform is to remove the relay and perform a continuity check (or an ohmmeter check) across the switch's contacts. With no power applied to the relay's coil, ensure the normally-closed (NC) input-output path has continuity (less than one ohm), and the normally-open (NO) input-output path is open circuit (infinite resistance). (NB: Digital ohmmeters indicate overload (OVLD) or similar for infinite resistance.)

Comment: @TomCarpenter, For what it's worth, the PLC provides a built-in flyback diode at each I/O channel. See the bottom figure labeled "Inside PLC" in Albert's question.

Comment: Thx for your reply Jim. I used the same relay and connect it to different power supply. This time I connected the relay's common directly to the psu 24V- and measured the psu 24V+ and relay's NO. I got 20 something mV which appears to be correct. Is there something to do with the terminal block? Or is the psu malfunctioned?

Comment: @AlbertTobing, just so I am clear, are you performing a voltage measurement across two points that ordinarily are not connected to any source of electrical power--e.g., on a terminal block, the meter probe is touching a screw that has nothing connected to it. If that is correct, and if the meter is consistently measuring 1 V across nodes that have no source of power, the first thing I'd do is get a different voltmeter (preferably a different brand and model number) and verify that it too measures 1 V. If both meters measure 1 V it's a circuit fault; otherwise it's an inaccurate meter.

Comment: That is what I am suspecting. Circuit fault. Problem is, I do not know where to spot the fault.. If you can tell me what caused it, maybe I can get a clue..

Comment: yes, you are correct. One point is the 24V+. Another point is supposedly not connected to anything ( relay's NO that iis not powered ).

Comment: I have tested the relay and they are as you mentioned. Com and NO is infinite. Com and NC is 0.1 ohm. NC and NO is infinite.

Comment: Also, I have four plcs with all Ground connected to terminal block's 24V- and VO connected to terminal block's 24V+. I am not sure if that will cause any issue.

Comment: PLC datasheet is : http://velocio.net/BranchDatasheet.pdf
Model is 1 x Branch and 3 x Exp 22. As you can see, one plc has four blocks. Two blocks of digital input and two blocks of digital output. Each input block has one GND that is connected to terminal block's 24V- and each output block has one VO that is connected to terminal block's 24V+ and GND that is connected to 24V-